# Reporting a tax refund from a previous year as income

Tags: taxes, income-tax, canada

I'm wondering if I have to report income from my 2013 Canadian tax return on my 2014 Canadian tax return?

I'll be filing as a non-resident if that's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a tax refund does not count as income.

Because you got a refund in 2013 that means that you paid more tax than you owe to the government based on your 2012 income. They are simply refunding you the extra tax that you paid. This won't have any effect on your 2013 taxable income.